# Service not able to run twice

Tags: android, service, media-player

I am making a music player with a service but when i click a song in the music list, the music starts with no errors, but if i go back to the list and click another i get `Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer error (-38, 0)`

My onStart method in the service:

```
@Override
public void onStart(final Intent i, int startid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start music");

    re = 0;

    songUrl = i.getData().toString();

    streamMusic = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            try {
                re = 1;
                music.reset();
                music.setDataSource(songUrl);
                music.prepare();

                this.interrupt();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    streamMusic.start();

}
```

I start the service with `startService(i);` and I have set a `music.setOnPreparedListener` so nothing is runned to early.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling reset() method before calling prepare again.
Also, if you are calling prepare() and not prepareAsync() I don't see why you need to use the prepared listener.

Comment: I am calling reset() before prepare..? I need the prepared listener to make sure that the music is prepared before i call like music.getDuration or I get an error.